# How to update() DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working with DynamoDB for the first time and so far, not too bad.  Having some understanding of Node is making this easier, but having none of noSQL, well that hurts!.  My application relies on quickly searching a GROUPS list and returning members from that group.

When I add the data using the console, I am able to create a JSON document like this:

```
"GROUP_ID":"GroupA", "MEMBER": ["MemberA", "MemberB", "MemberC"], "STATUS": ["OWNER", "MEMBER", "INVITED"], "ADD_DATE":[1234567, 2345671, 3456712]
```

I am using this to create the GROUP_ID as the primary key:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var tableName = "USER_GROUPS";
    var checkParams = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Key:{"GROUP_NAME": event.group_id}
    };
    var createParams = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Key:{"GROUP_NAME": event.group_id},
        Item:{"GROUP_NAME": event.group_id, "MEMBER_NAME":[event.device_id], "MEMBER_SATUS":["OWNER"], "MEMBER_DATE" : [event.date]}
    };

    var checkGroupExists = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        docClient.get(checkParams, (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
            if(data.Item){  // exists... 
                console.log("found Group ID");
                reject();
            }
            else{
                console.log("Group ID not found...");
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });

    checkGroupExists.then((err, data) => {
        console.log("adding Group: ");
        console.log(data);
        docClient.put(createParams, (err, data) =>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                callback(err, null);
            }else{
                console.log("added device: " + createParams.Key);
                callback(null, {"created":createParams.Key.GROUP_NAME});
            }
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else{
            callback(err, {"used":createParams.Key.GROUP_NAME});
        }
    });
};
```

but when I use update() I am adding to the array and end up with a type name for the arrays

```
["S":"MemberA", "S":"MemberB", "S":"MemberC"]
```

kind of thing....

This is where I have left off, quite frustrated here!

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var tableName = "USER_GROUPS";
    var checkParams = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Key:{"GROUP_NAME": event.group_id},
        Item:{"MEMBER_NAME": event.member_name}
    };
    var updateParams = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Key:{"GROUP_NAME": event.group_id},
        //Item:{"MEMBER_NAME":[event.device_id], "MEMBER_STATUS":["OWNER"], "MEMBER_DATE" : [event.date]},
        AttributeUpdates: {
            "MEMBER_NAME": {
                Action: 'ADD',
                Value: event.device_id
            },
            "MEMBER_STATUS":{
                Action : 'ADD',
                Value: "ENVITED"
            },
            "MEMBER_DATE":{
                Action: 'ADD',
                Value: event.date
            }
        },
    };



    var checkGroupExists = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        docClient.get(checkParams, (err, data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
            if(data.Item.GROUP_NAME){  // exists... 
                console.log("found the group...");
                resolve();
            }
            else{
                reject();
            }
        });
    });

    checkGroupExists.then((err, data) => {
        docClient.update(updateParams, (err, data) =>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                callback(err, null);
            }else{
                callback(null, {"updated" : updateParams.Key.GROUP_NAME});
            }
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else{
            callback(err, {"noGroup":createParams.Key.GROUP_NAME});
        }
    });
};
```

It seems I am lacking the understanding of how to process updates to include NEW item in the member array.  Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`list_append()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.SET.Functions) together in an [UpdateExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions) to append to a list column along with a [`ConditionExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.ConditionExpressions) to prevent updates to a non-existent group:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const DB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-east-1'});
const UpdateExpression = 'SET ' + [
  '#members = list_append(#members, :member)',
  '#statuses = list_append(#statuses, :status)',
  '#dates = list_append(#dates, :date)',
].join(', ')
const ConditionExpression = [
  'attribute_type(#members, :L)',
  'attribute_type(#statuses, :L)',
  'attribute_type(#dates, :L)'
].join(' AND ')
const ExpressionAttributeNames = {
  '#members': 'MEMBER_NAME',
  '#statuses': 'MEMBER_STATUS',
  '#dates': 'MEMBER_DATE'
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  DB.update({
    TableName: 'USER_GROUPS',
    Key: { GROUP_NAME: e.group_id },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
    UpdateExpression: UpdateExpression,
    ConditionExpression: ConditionExpression,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: ExpressionAttributeNames,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':member': [e.member_name],
      ':status': ['ENVITED'],
      ':date': [e.date],
      ':L': 'L'
    }
  }, callback)
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that.. completely refactored, wow.  I'm seeing "errorMessage": "The conditional request failed", "errorType": "ConditionalCheckFailedException",  I'm having difficulty understanding the syntax there!

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton that error should indicate that the row you're attempting to update doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks I created a row using the first lambda I posted above.  Then, trying to use the same key "GROUP_NAME" with your code, I only get that error.  I have to say, this is not intuitive at all!  PS. i did have to update the event variable names in the .handler, but I don't think that matters...

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton try removing the `ConditionExpression` line in the handler and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I feel like I'm wasting your time.. commenting out the ConditionExpression line in the handler gave me a new error: "errorMessage": "Value provided in ExpressionAttributeValues unused in expressions: keys: {:L}",
  "errorType": "ValidationException",